# Parse Error: Unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: php, parsing, parse-error, php-parse-error

I am receiving the following parse error on line 16: 'syntax error, unexpected T_STRING'. That being said, the following block of codes parses correctly with PHP 5.4.16, however, does not parse correctly with PHP 4.4.9. Thoughts?

To me, the error is suggesting that the `interface` keyword was not supported in PHP 4.4.9, however, I could not find that in PHP's change log.

```
interface iA { // line 16
  public function methodA();
  public function methodB();
  public function methodC();
}
```

**EDIT (providing full snippet)**

```
<?php

// a comment.
// a comment.
// a comment.
// a comment.
// a comment.
// a comment.

// a comment.
if (!defined('PRODUCT_ENV')) {
  exit;
}

// a comment.
interface iA {
  public function methodA();
  public function methodB();
  public function methodC();
}

include(PRODUCT_PWD . PRODUCT_IMPLES . 'anotherfile.php');
```

Comment: Yes, you need PHP 5 for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the [New Object Model](http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php) section of the [Migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5.0.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.php) chapter of the PHP manual. Documentation of the old PHP/4 object model has been moved to the [Classes and Objects (PHP 4)](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.php) appendix.

PHP/5 was released exactly 10 years ago (July 2004) so it's pretty rare to find support for PHP 4 anywhere.